# Whitespace stripped from input on AWS Automation Document

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I'm trying to use an AWS Automation Document to generate new AMI's with security updates.

I have an input parameter for the command I want to run on the ec2 machine before generating the new image. If that input parameter is of type "String", everything works fine. If it is of type "StringList" then I lose all the whitespace.

Example with input type "String":

In the input field I enter: `sudo yum -y update --security`. Document receives and runs this command on the ec2 machine: `sudo yum -y update --security`. Everything works correctly.

Example with input type "StringList":

In the input field I enter: `sudo yum -y update --security`. Document receives and attempts to run this command on the ec2 machine: `sudoyum-yupdate--security`. Receive an error because the command cannot be found.

Is there anyway I can have it not strip out the whitespace? I know I can just use type "String" for the input parameter and it will work, but I'd like to have the option of passing in multiple commands to run if possible.

Comment: Please post your code